# Flutter Error: Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: android, flutter

I am attempting to run a flutter project on Android studio(V3.5)and getting the error below.
This is happening for both older and new projects.
The solutions i have tried are:

**1. flutter clean.
 2. upgrading flutter sdk.
 3. reinstalling the flutter sdk.
 4. checked that user folder name has no spaces
 5. created an environment variable called ANDROID_HOME and set its
    value to the path of the android sdk
 6. Invalidate caches/ Restart**

but neither of these work.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

  Command: C:\Users\shiru\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.EXE dump xmltree C:\Users\shiru\FlutterProjects\mobile_bank\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
Problem building Android application: see above error(s).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the android SDK tools did the trick.